# Not able to export more than 1000 rows via googleAnalyticsR

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the library to export more than 6 months of data.

The total amount of rows of my export in the interface is around 2000 rows.

When I replicate the report via the package I systematically get 1000 rows.

Is there a way to export the total amount of rows?

My code looks like - simply:

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
my_id <- 123456
ga_auth()

df_ga <- google_analytics(my_id, 
                       date_range = c("2018-12-04", "2019-09-04"),
                       metrics = c("sessions"),
                       dimensions = c("transactionId","sourceMedium","deviceCategory",'region',"city","hour","channelGrouping","userType") )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [Max rows](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/v4.html#number-of-results) in order to request additional rows.

```
# 1000 rows only
thousand <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
                             date_range = c("2017-01-01", "2017-03-01"), 
                             metrics = "sessions", 
                             dimensions = "date")

# 2000 rows
twothousand <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
                             date_range = c("2017-01-01", "2017-03-01"), 
                             metrics = "sessions", 
                             dimensions = "date",
                             max = 2000)  

# All rows
alldata <- google_analytics(ga_id, 
                             date_range = c("2017-01-01", "2017-03-01"), 
                             metrics = "sessions", 
                             dimensions = "date",
                             max = -1)
```